# Implement Serializable to a class implementing an Interface

Tags: java, interface, implementation, serializable, implements

I have this super class named **Person** which is inherited by two other classes, **Employee** & **Client**
I am using an interface so as I can use generics on the two sub classes and hence the Person class implements this interface, **Searchable**. Is it possible for the Person class to implement both the interface and Serializable so I can save?

```
package compuwiz;
public abstract class Person implements Searchable //implements Serializable ??
{
public Person()
{
    pName = "";
    pSurname = "";
    pIdCard = "";
}
public Person(String nm, String sn, String id)
{
    pName = nm;
    pSurname = sn;
    pIdCard = id;
}
String pName;
String pSurname;
String pIdCard;
public String GetName()
{
    return pName;
}
public String GetSurname()
{
    return pSurname;
}

@Override
public String GetID()
{
    return pIdCard;
}
//Set Methods
public void SetName(String nm) 
{
  pName=nm;  
}
public void SetSurname(String sn) 
{
  pSurname=sn;  
} 
public void SetID(String id) 
{
  pIdCard=id;  
}

@Override
public String ToString()
{
    return this.GetName()+ " " +this.GetSurname()+ "ID card number:" +this.GetID();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's the purpose of interfaces. A class can implement multiple interfaces at the same time:

```
public abstract class Person implements Searchable, Serializable {
    //current code of your class...
}
```

Besides this, I would recommend using proper naming of your methods. This is, use `camelCase` standard, the first letter goes in lower case, then you use upper case for the next word contained in the name. Example:

```
//this will throw a compiler error unless you define a ToString method in a top interface
@Override
public String ToString() {
}
```

To

```
@Override
public String toString() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class Person implements Serializable, Searchable {}
```

Java suppports multiple interface inheritance